# How to show categories when search on google my web?

Tags: search, categories

please help me to show categories on google when someone search for my website..[CLICK HERE THIS IS A EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdheA.png)

Answer (score 4):

It's not something you can straightforwardly set up. Google will determine whether sitelinks are displayed for your search result.

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47334